# Chrome flag --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app, selenium-chromedriver

I am using `--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://localhost:8575 --test-type --user-data-dir=c:\temp\` for my local http server to communicate with in HTTPS, But since chrome update **Version 53.0.2785.101 m** it is not working, Any idea or workaround ?

Comment: The flag is still supported according to [source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/common/secure_origin_whitelist.cc?sq=package:chromium&rcl=1473419928&l=20), so 1) try running Chrome Canary and 2) if it doesn't work, report a bug on https://crbug.com